# use viewmodel property in model and notify the same property changed in model to viewmodel to bind to view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

SingleMessage.xaml has viewmodel as SingleMessageViewModel.cs and this viewmodel uses LogAcitvity class as property and the property defined in the viewmodel is bind to the SingleMessage.xaml. 
Now I want to use this(viewmodel) property in SocketClient.cs(Model) and want to notify the property change in the viewmodel to update the view.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {   
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

LogActivity class whose property is used in the viewmodel

```
public class LogActivity : ViewModelBase
{      
    private string messageLog;
    public string MessageLog
    {
        get { return messageLog; }
        set
        {
            if (value != messageLog)
            {
                messageLog = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageLog");
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

This is my viewmodel class

```
public class SingleMessageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private LogActivity messagelog;

    public SingleMessageViewModel()
    {
        messagelog = new LogActivity();
    }   

    public LogActivity MessageLog
    {
        get { return messagelog; }
        set
        {
            if (value != messagelog)
            {
                messagelog = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageLog");
            }
        }
    }  
 }
```

this is my view

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtLog" Text="{Binding MessageLog.MessageLog, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

Now I want to use this MessageLog property in the viewmodel in my SocketClient.cs model class and want to notify its change to viewmodel.
So that update happens to view. And also this propety is changed in the asynchorous method call so I want to use the this syntaxt to update the viewmodel property :

```
public class SocketClient : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
    {
       MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : <- "  + szData.Replace("\n\0", "") + "\n";
    });
}
```

So, how to use the viewmodel propety this in the model and notify it to the viewmodel

```
public LogActivity MessageLog
{
    get { return messagelog; }
    set
    {
        if (value != messagelog)
        {
            messagelog = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageLog");
        }
    }
}
```

My model looks like this..

```
namespace PCSTESTGUI.Models
{   

public class SocketClient : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Receive buffer.       
    byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[256];
    IAsyncResult result;
    public AsyncCallback pfnCallBack;
    public Socket clientSocket;
    private LogActivity messagelog;
    //private SingleMessageViewModel SingleMVM;
    int portNo;
    string ipAddress;
    string filePathName;
    string receivedResponse;
    string message = string.Empty;
    string connstring = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlConfigurationSetting"].ToString();
    string fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlConfiguratonSettingFileName"].ToString();
    string messageTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

        public SocketClient()
        {
            messagelog = new LogActivity();
            SingleMessageViewModel SingleMVM = new SingleMessageViewModel(this);            
            //get the IPAddress and PortNo from save configuration setting
            filePathName = connstring + "\\" + fileName;
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(filePathName))
                {
                    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePathName);
                    var configsetting = from cs in xdoc.Descendants("ConfigurationSetting")
                                        select cs;
                    foreach (var config in configsetting)
                    {
                        ipAddress = config.Element("IPAddress").Value;
                        portNo = Convert.ToInt16(config.Element("PortNo").Value);
                    }
                    // check ipaddress and port no exists
                    if (ipAddress == "" || portNo == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("IP Address and Port Number are required to connect to the Server\n", "Socket Connection : Missing", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                        FileLogger.Handle("Missing IP Address / Port Number in the configuration settings file");
                        MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : Missing IP Address / Port Number in the configuration settings file\n";
                        return;
                    }
                    //connect to the server
                    ConnectServer();
                }              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                FileLogger.Handle(ex.Message);
                MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : " + ex.Message + "\n";

            }
        }
        public SingleMessageViewModel SingleMVM
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public LogActivity  MessageLog
        {
            get
            {
                return messagelog;
            }
            set
            {
                messagelog = value;
                this.SingleMVM.MessageLog = value;            
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageLog");              
            }
        }

        public void ConnectServer()
        { 
            try
            {   
                // Get the remote IP address
                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
                int iPortNo = portNo;
                // Create the socket instance
                clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                FileLogger.Handle("StartConnect - Trying socket connection to PCS server '" + ip.ToString() + "' on Port " + iPortNo.ToString());
                MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : StartConnect - Trying socket connection to PCS server '" + ip.ToString() + "' on Port " + iPortNo.ToString() + "\n";

                // Create the end point 
                IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, iPortNo);
                // Connect to the remote host
                clientSocket.Connect(ipEnd);
                if (clientSocket.Connected)
                {
                    FileLogger.Handle("ProcessConnect - Client socket connected to PCS server '" + ip.ToString() + "' on Port " + iPortNo.ToString());
                    MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : ProcessConnect - Client socket connected to PCS server '" + ip.ToString() + "' on Port " + iPortNo.ToString() + "\n";

                    //Wait for data asynchronously 
                    WaitForData();
                }
                else
                {
                    ConnectServer();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                FileLogger.Handle(ex.Message);
                MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : " + ex.Message + "\n";
            }
        }

        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            try
            {                
                if (!clientSocket.Connected)
                    ConnectServer();

                if (message != "")
                {
                    this.message = message + "\r\n";
                    byte[] byteMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.message);
                    //NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(clientSocket);
                    //StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
                    //streamWriter.WriteLine(byteMessage);
                    //streamWriter.Flush();
                    if (clientSocket != null && clientSocket.Connected)
                    {
                        FileLogger.Handle("Pseudo Command message processing tasks started");
                        FileLogger.Handle(" -> " + message.ToUpper());
                        MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : Pseudo Command message processing tasks started\n";
                        MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : -> " + message.ToUpper() + "\n";
                        clientSocket.Send(byteMessage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ConnectServer();
                        if (clientSocket.Connected)
                        {
                            FileLogger.Handle("Pseudo Command message processing tasks started");
                            FileLogger.Handle(" -> " + message.ToUpper());
                            MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : Pseudo Command message processing tasks started\n";
                            MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : -> " + message.ToUpper() + "\n";
                            clientSocket.Send(byteMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                FileLogger.Handle(ex.Message);
                MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : " + ex.Message + "\n";
            }
        }

        public void DissconnectServer()
        {   
            clientSocket.Close();
            clientSocket = null;
            FileLogger.Handle("CloseConnection - Closed socket connection to PCS server '" + ipAddress + "' on Port " + portNo.ToString());
            MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : ProcessConnect - Client socket connected to PCS server '" + ipAddress + "' on Port " + portNo.ToString() + "\n";
        }

        public class SocketPacket
        {
            public System.Net.Sockets.Socket thisSocket;
            public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
        }

        public void WaitForData()
        {
            try
            {
                if (pfnCallBack == null)
                {
                    pfnCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
                }
                SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket();
                theSocPkt.thisSocket = clientSocket;
                // Start listening to the data asynchronously
                result = clientSocket.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0, theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length,
                                                      SocketFlags.None, pfnCallBack, theSocPkt);

                if (result.IsCompleted == false)
                {
                    Console.Write(".");
                }

            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                FileLogger.Handle(se.Message);
                MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : " + se.Message + "\n";
            }
        }

        public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {
            try
            {               
                SocketPacket theSockId = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
                int iRx = theSockId.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
                char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
                System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                int charLen = d.GetChars(theSockId.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
                System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
                receivedResponse = receivedResponse + szData + "\n";
                if (szData.ToString() != "\0" || szData.ToString() != "")
                {
                    FileLogger.Handle(" <- " + szData.Replace("\n\0", ""));

                    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
                    {
                        MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : <- " + szData.Replace("\n\0", "") + "\n";
                        if (SingleMVM == null)
                            SingleMVM = new SingleMessageViewModel(this);
                        //this.SingleMVM.MessageLog.MessageLog += this.MessageLog.MessageLog;
                        this.SingleMVM.updateMesssage(szData.Replace("\n\0", ""));
                    });

                } 

                WaitForData();
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {                
                FileLogger.Handle(ex.Message);
                MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : " + ex.Message + "\n";               
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                FileLogger.Handle(se.Message);
                MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : " + se.Message + "\n";               
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the OnDataReceived funtion the data is received from the server and that need to be updated to view via viewmodel property MessageLog.
The INofication is not raising the event as PropertyChanged is null.
But I am asingning the value to the value.

In the viewmodel reading this value like this and it is also notify the propert call, but property changed is null so the event isnot raised.

```
public void updateMesssage(string message)
{            
    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, new Action(() =>
    {
        this.MessageLog.MessageLog += messageTimeStamp + " : <- " + message + "\n";
    }));
}
```

Comment: where is your Model ?

Comment: How do you connect your view with the view model? If the property changed event is null (is that true?) this means that no listener (e.g. the view) has registered to the event.